# SQL Server 2008 Geospatial queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

SQL Server 2008 has new geo data types. One thing I am wondering though is that if I have a table with geocoded addresses in it, can I write a query to display all records within a certain distance. For example, many websites have the option to search for items within a certain distance such as 50 miles and would like it if SQL 2008 provided this out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of query a [spatial index](http://www.rtreeportal.org/) is designed to support.  [This blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/isaac/archive/2007/05/16/sql-server-spatial-support-an-introduction.aspx) gives a quick introduction that includes this type of query.